# tun/tap interface cannot reach the internet

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, networkmanager, route

I am trying to set up a NAT: a tun/tap interface `tap0`, with IP masquerading.

But i cannot reach the internet through `tap0` when the default route is through it. Can you help me troubleshoot please?

These are the commands i have run, where `192.168.A.B` is a placeholder for the address of `tap0`:

```
ip tuntap add mode tap tap0
ip addr add 192.168.A.B/24 dev tap0
ifconfig tap0 192.168.A.B up
ip route add default via 192.168.A.B
ip link set tap0 up`
```

And these are my `iptables` rules, with some of them specific to another user named someuser, while i was root when i was doing my tests (so those with `owner UID match someuser` are not relevant) :

```
[root@localhost ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere localhost owner UID match someuser tcp dpt:krb524
ACCEPT udp -- anywhere localhost owner UID match someuser udp dpt:krb524
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere localhost owner UID match someuser tcp dpt:upnotifyp
ACCEPT udp -- anywhere localhost owner UID match someuser udp dpt:upnotifyp
REJECT all -- anywhere anywhere owner UID match someuser reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

[root@localhost ~]# iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
MASQUERADE all -- 192.168.A.0/24 anywhere
MASQUERADE all -- anywhere anywhere
```

At this point, when i `ping imdb.com` , the host is unreachable. Are the MASQUERADE iptables rules to blame?

This is the output of `ip route`, where `eth0` is the real interface with address `192.168.X.Y` and my gateway   is `192.168.X.Z`

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip route
default via 192.168.A.B dev tap0 linkdown
default via 192.168.X.Z dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.X.Y metric 100
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 metric 30
192.168.X.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.X.Y metric 100
192.168.A.0/24 dev tap0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.A.B metric 350 linkdown
```

Even though it says "linkdown", `tap0` seems up:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> ...
...
tap0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 192.168.A.B netmask [255.255.255.0](https://255.255.255.0)  broadcast 192.168.A.255
```

`ip addr show` shows this for tap0:

```
tap0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

and this for eth0

```
<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
```

Now, if i do the following, the ping works

```
ip route delete default via 192.168.A.B
```

Just to say that everything works through my real gateway directly.

Something that i can try: creating a bridge through `nmcli`/`nmtui`, between `tap0` and `eth0`. Would it fix it and how to do that?

Comment: Can you show your `server.conf`  config file using something like `awk '!/^#|^;/ && NF' /etc/openvpn/server.conf` config on the vpn server and your config on the client?

Comment: A tap interface is actually working only when there's an userspace program handling it (eg: QEMU, OpenVPN, openssh ...). That's why you get linkdown: no userspace tool on the other side. I guess you might not understand what's the role of a tap interface.

Comment: You should describe *what* you intend to do, but now *how* you intend to do it, considering that if it worked *how* you intend to do it, there wouldn't be any question asked. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Maybe you're attempting to have a dual-homed setup, but you'll have to present it with all the relevant information.